# Замена повторяющихся строк на пустое значение при выводе таблици

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query =  "SELECT category,name,brand,count,price,count*price,unit FROM goods order by category";
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $query) or die ('Error');

if($result)
{
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<table  border='3' bgcolor='#696969'><tr><td>Category</td><td>Name</td><td>Brand</td><td>Count</td><td>Price</td><td>Summary price</td><td>Unit tovar</td></tr>";
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 0 ; $j < 7 ; ++$j) echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";


    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Нужно заменить повторяющиеся значения category на пустое значение при выводе таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И с чем возникла проблема?

Comment: if($result)
{
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<table  border='3'><tr><td>Category</td><td>Name</td><td>Brand</td><td>Count</td><td>Price</td><td>Summary price</td><td>Unit</td></tr>";
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 0 ; $j < 7 ; ++$j){
            if($i === 0 && $j > 0 && $row[$j] === $row[$j - 1]) echo "<td></td>";
            else echo "<td>$row[$j]</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";


    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

Comment: не работает етот способ

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете добавить переменную для проверки повторяющейся категории. Например, так:

```
//...
$current_category = -1;
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $rows ; ++$i){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j = 0 ; $j < 7 ; ++$j){
        echo "<td>";
        if($j == 0){
            if($row[$j] != $current_category){
                // если категория новая, выводим ее и делаем текущей.
                echo $row[$j];
                $current_category = $row[$j];
            }
        } else {
            echo $row[$j];
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
//...
```